# how to open a facebook login page in a iframe insted of popup

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook login button in website. when i clicked on that it opens a popup. insted of popup i want to open that in a iframe. is there any way to do that using javascript.
plz help me.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't integrate Facebook in your website like that. Facebook is another website, so please don't blend it into your own.

Comment: I agree with pimvdb - it sounds like either bad usability or a malicious website.

Answer (score 3):

Show some of your code. Is the code that opens the popup yours or included from some other site? If it's not your own code and it uses `window.open`, there's nothing much you can do.

If it's your code, use something like this onClick: `document.getElementByID('iFrameID').src=url;`

Keep in mind that if the facebook-login (which will be an external page) expects to be running in a popup window could execute `window.close` to return to your page, which may cause problems if you're using an iFrame.